# ativar transparencia total do background png no form

Tags: c#, winforms

Bom eu tenho um form c# porém eu uso uma render png, que contem uns efeitos sombras e fumaça, a única maneira que achei para dar a transparência foi o key, mas ele não fica totalmente transparente, imagem de exemplo abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu queria saber, se tem alguma maneira de deixar totalmente transparente.

Comment: veja se esse link te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387680/transparent-background-on-winforms

Comment: continua a não funcionar o codigo de solução, fica esse efeito mesmo com o lime

Answer (score 0):

Você pode cancelar o evento onde o BackGround é pintado e preencher com uma imagem desta forma:

```
public SeuForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
}
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //Definir sua imagem.
    Image newImage = Properties.Resources
        ._0_cKbBcUPJTfpFwuQi_;

    //Posição e tamanho da imagem
    //Aconselho deixar o seu form do tamanho da imagem já design time, para facilitar o desenvolvimento
    //ou pode setar os tamanhos do form para o da imagem pelo codigo tambem(ex: this.Width = newImage.Width;)

    //Caso deseje centralizar a imagem automaticamente:
    //x = (Width - newImage.Width) / 2; y = (Height - newImage.Height) / 2;
    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;

    //Desenhar imagem
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, x, y, width, height);
}
```

[image: Resultado]

Não é lá uma boa pratica, mas não vejo outra maneira de atingir o resultado que deseja em WF.

Comment: agora o bakcground fira totalmente preto https://imgur.com/a/qR0QG